# Issue with And Or operators in PHP

Tags: php

I am facing issue with PHP operators. Below is my code.

When I open the page I am not getting anything. As you can see there are two kind of login can be done. If no one is logged in then it will show **Hi Guest**.

But at the moment nothing is showing. I checked my code multiple times but I didn't found the issue.

As per my understanding, issue would be in if condition.

```
    $uid=$_SESSION['uid']; 
    $name=$_SESSION['name'];
    $pic = $_SESSION['pic'];
    $emp_id=$_SESSION['emp_id'];
    $emp_name=$_SESSION['fname'];

    if($pic==""){
       $pic = "/img/noimage.png"; 
        }
    if(($uid != '' and $name != '') or ($emp_id != '' and $emp_name != ''))
                {
                   if($emp_name != ''){
                   $name = $emp_name;
                }
    echo '<a href="phome.php">
<img src ="'.$pic.'" width="35" height="30" alt="'.$name.'"></img></a>';
echo '<li><a href="/settings.php" title="Settings"><i class="fa fa-gears"></i></a></li>';
                    echo ' ';
echo '<li><a href="/logout.php" title="Logout"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i></a></li>';
                        }
                        if($uid == '' and $name == '' and $emp_id == '' and $emp_name == '')
                            {
                                echo '<b><font color="#fff">Hi, Guest</font></b>'; 
                                echo '<li> </li>';
                                echo '&nbsp;';
                                echo ' ';
                                echo '<li><a href="/register.php"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></a></li>';                 
                            }
```

Comment: So check values of you variables right before `if ($uid == '' and $name == '' and $emp_id...)` Obviously one or more of them is not empty.

Comment: You could use an `else` instead of a second `if`.

Comment: @u_mulder Thanks for your comment. It means my code is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(($uid == '' OR $name == '') and ($emp_id == '' OR $emp_name == ''))
{
    echo '<b><font color="#fff">Hi, Guest</font></b>';
    echo '<li> </li>';
    echo '&nbsp;';
    echo ' ';
    echo '<li><a href="/register.php"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></a></li>';
}
```